# PerformSegueWithIdentifier suddenly firing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, viewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have ViewController A and ViewController B. I have correctly set up an unwind segue so I can pop back from B to A. However, I have a IBAction connected to a button in B, and when I tap that one, it should perform the unwind segue.
The problem is - as soon as I get into View Controller B, after 1 second or so, it just performs the segue even though I didn't get to click anything. Is there any solution how to fix this?

Comment: is there any way you can share a sample project (via github, bitbucket, etc.) illustrating the case?

Comment: or could you atleast give us some screenshots?

Comment: Can you post the code that's in view controllers A and B so that we can see how you set up the segues?

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/5215474